# How do I only allow a certain UDID/Device to successfully install an iOS Profile (mobileconfig)

Tags: ios, iphone, security, udid, serial-number

I want to deploy an iOS profile with sensitive data onto certain devices. I don't want the user to be able to re-distribute that profile by plugging it into the computer. I want the profile to only install on certain devices that have the correct UDID or Serial Number etc. I also would like to accomplish this without using a server. So if the file did get leaked, others would not be able to install because they don't have the correct UDID. 
How can I go about completing this?

Thanks in advance :D